# Print memory addresses of chars in a string with (void*) cast

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I'm experimenting with bracket and pointer syntax in C++ to cement my understanding of each. Reading other StackOverflow questions, I'm aware that in order to print a memory address with `std::cout` I must cast the value using `(void *)`. I also saw recommendations to use `std::addressof`. My syntax in this question is strictly for learning and not representative of my notion of best practices.

For a string "Hello, World" as `argv[1]`, I'm able to print the memory location of each character using the following:

```
  for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
    std::cout << "Letter: " << argv[1][i] << " Address: " << (void*)&argv[1][i] << std::endl;
  }
```

I would expect the same outcome using this notation:

```
for (char *c = argv[1]; *c != '\0'; c++) {
    std::cout << "Letter: " << *c << " Address: " << (void*)&c << std::endl;
  }
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Letter: H Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: e Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: l Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: l Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: o Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: , Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter:   Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: W Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: o Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: r Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: l Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
Letter: d Address: 0x7ffee4e05788
```

My understanding is that...

- c is a pointer to a char
- *c is the value of the pointee
- &c is the memory address held by the pointer
- c++ increments c to the memory address of the next char

So, I should see a unique memory address printed for each char. What might explain this outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is a variable that holds a pointer (address) to a character; its value changes with each loop iteration.  `&c` (which is what you are printing) is the address of that variable; it stays constant.

Comment: Aha, so I should use (void*)&(*c)

Comment: Just omit the ampersand